# Image crop с динамически уменьшенной картинкой

Tags: jquery, изображения, php, javascript

Всем привет, кто-то знает image crop на javascript/jquery, который умеет работать с 'уменьшенной в css картинкой'?

То есть, все кропальщики отлично работают, если юзеру дать оригинальный размер картинки (размерами допустим 400px x 400px) с width:100%;  Но если вывести юзеру картинку размерами 1500px x 1500px и уменьшить ее размеры в css до 100px x 100px (просто потому что 1500 не влазит в экран и не красиво это), то кропальщики, что мне попадались тут же паникуют и выдают либо ошибки, либо обрезают по начальным значениям, т.е. верхний левый угол. Мне фотки с фейсбука нужно вытаскивать, а они там большие. Вариант уменьшать размер фотки до вывода юзеру - тоже не вариант, потому что портится качество.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ндам, говорили ведь, учи математику, в школе. Все оказалось просто, но чтобы прийти к этой мысли, пришлось убить сутки...

формула: оригинальный размер картинки делим на тот, что получился после "css уменьшения", получаем коэффициент. Перед отправкой на кроп - умножаем точки x1, y1 и ширину, высоту на этот коэффициент. profit!

Закройте кто-то вопрос, пожалуйста, я не могу, а удалять не хочу.